# Copying values from one Table to the first empty row in another Table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

As part of my project I have a Table which includes lookup formulas in each column that are dragged down the whole table. Depending on the case only the first x rows return values. I included an iferror so that the lookups that don't return values return "".

Now I want to copy the rows of the table that return values to the first empty row in a different table in a different worksheet.

The code I have so far: 
    Sub Copy_Results()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

copySheet.Range("Table1").Copy
pasteSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.Cells(Rows.Count,  1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now the big problem is that I want to be able to execute this macro multiple times, each time the values from Table 1 should be pasted below the preexisting values in table 2.

The point being that each time the lookup values change meaning I get new results I want to paste them in a table where all the results are documented.

Issues that I had so far:
The first Copy Paste usually works, but when I copy again the values get pasted way below the first ones outside of the table. Usually the full length of the table away. I guess this is because the whole copy table is filled with formulas.

Comment: tbh, I don't see how this even works with an unqualified `Rows.Count` since there cannot be `ListObjects("Table2").Range.Cells(Rows.Count,  1)...` unless the table starts in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to restrict the cells that you are going to copy using the SpecialCells method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx

In this case you only want to copy the formulas that have numbers as the values, so this would be the syntax:

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
```

Put into your code it would be:

```
copySheet.Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy
```

You can see this in action outside of your code by selecting the complete range in your source sheet then pressing F5, selecting the "Special" button at the bottom of the dialog that pops up, then select "Formulas" and "Numbers".

To make sure it pastes in the next available row, use the CurrentRegion property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This code will tell you what the last row is in the used area defined by cell A1:

```
pasteSheet.cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

I believe the paste command you're looking for will be close to this (hard to test exactly without your spreadsheet):

```
pasteSheet.cells(pasteSheet.cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try this out!

Comment: Was stuck in a meeting until now just tested you solution. It partly works it only copies the correct range now but still pastes it seemingly into random rows below the table. Is there an easy way to make it so it will be paste in the first empty row within the tabe?

Comment: Modified solution with one way to handle that

Comment: I get the error: Object required. Wondering what you mean by last row that is in the used area defined by cell A1? My Table starts in column B maybe that is the issue here? Sadly I am bloody useless with VBA... Originally I thought this should be a really basic thing to do in VBA apparently once Tables get involved it is not. Thanks for your help though really appreciate it.

Comment: Tables are a pain in Excel, I never use them.  The issue is probably due to your sheet starting in column 2/B, it's tough for me to write the exact code you need as I can't see your exact workbook :)

Comment: I have to say I am actually a fan of Tables since it makes defining ranges general lookups so much easier and cleaner. My non VBA knowing brain just assumed that you could refer to the paste table similar as how I copied it just say range("table") paste.. But still thanks for trying to help I will see how far I get with trial and error.